# Ubuntu doesnt want to start!

Tags: boot

I have a DVD with Ubuntu on it. When I restart my PC (with the Ubuntu disc inserted) nothing happens. Windows 8 just starts up. I tried with my friend's DVD as well. I have 3 discs with Ubuntu on them and none of them work! What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Look at the book order in the BIOS menu.

Comment: I also tried with LUBUNTU and XBUNTU and nothing happened. When i put the CD in friend's PC, the ubuntu starts normaly, but if i put CD in myne PC, nothing happers, windows 8 just starts, i tried everything!

Comment: ? what book, and how to get onto BIOS menu if i dont restart the PC

Comment: You need to make sure your computer's BIOS is configured to give boot priority to the CD.

Comment: I meant BOOT order. Sorry. Search Google on how to change the boot order of your PC.

Comment: Ill try it out, if doesnt work ill ask more...

Comment: ITS INSANE, imposible, its too hard >*

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What is your PC model?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Windows, open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open Windows Control Panel -> Power Settings and uncheck Fast startup.

In case it is not visible, enable show hidden settings.

Shutdown the machine completely - do NOT reboot.

Now you should be able to boot from Ubuntu DVD.